# Weird UITextField Placeholder Behaviour On RTL iOS9

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitextfield, ios9, placeholder

On creating the `UITextField` from a `xib` and calling the `resignFirstResponder()` method on RTL keyboard language the `UITextField` placeholder align is right.

On creating the textField programmatically and calling the `resignFirstResponder()` method on RTL keyboard language the `UITextField` placeholder align is left.

```
let txtField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
```

I want to use the `UITextField` from the `xib` file and not programmatically.

Note:
clearing all the constraints doesn’t help.
The problem is only in iOS 9

I don’t know why on creating the `UITextField` from the `xib` file the placeholder behave differently,

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `semanticContentAttribute` (a property of `UIView`) that let you determine the direction of the layout LTR/RTL.

It was introduced on iOS 9 as part of an improved system support for RTL and it might be the cause for the difference you see between iOS 8 and 9.

Comment: so this property need to be?

Answer (score 0):

RTL is right to left script so the placeholder in the xib file seems to be doing the right thing as the user would start at the right. Do you want the placeholder on the left still?

Comment: Thanks, Yes I want the placeholder on the left still RTL or LTR

Comment: @BenjaminHalimi When you run it on an actual device, is it still on the right?

Comment: on the left if I writing with RTL keyboard language the placeholder jump on the right where the cursor is.